# Port blocked from network

Tags: windows, port, data-protector

Situation:
Windows Server 2003 R2 running HP Data Protector Client
Port 5555 is blocked. Telnet to Server:5555 from the network fails but works from the machine itself. Firewall is disabled. AV is disabled/uninstalled. Disabled the Data Protector client. Installed SSH server with port 5555 and 5556. Port 5556 works as expected. 5555 is blocked. Performed Winsock reset. Connected second NIC and tried with that. This machine was infected and problem occurred a few weeks after cleaning up that unknown virus.

I'll take any ideas at this point. Sacrifice 2 chickens and a gerbil?

Comment: `This machine was infected...` means that a rebuild is in order.

Comment: And what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know nothing about HP Data Protector but you could check if service listening on port 5555 is binded to the right network interface (and not loopback only).